# Unable to load R kernel in Jupyter notebook, Kernel Died

Tags: python, r, docker, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

unable to load shared object '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so'
I am trying to install Anaconda with R-kernal on RHEL 7 docker image,  the file is available (not missing) /opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so. It's working fine with Ubuntu/debian, but not working in RHEL

```
[I 07:18:08.758 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
[I 07:18:11.765 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
[W 07:18:13.631 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 16378669-1910-4cda-868e-2bb6860f7664
[I 07:18:14.770 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
kernel 16378669-1910-4cda-868e-2bb6860f7664 restarted
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
[W 07:18:17.777 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 07:18:17.778 NotebookApp] Kernel 16378669-1910-4cda-868e-2bb6860f7664 died, removing from map.
kernel 16378669-1910-4cda-868e-2bb6860f7664 restarted failed!
[W 07:18:18.134 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 07:18:18.135 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/e89223dd-d8e6-4104-b1ef-f161bc69a1b5 (10.66.192.88) 1.86ms referer=http://<Host_name>:8888/notebooks/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=ir
[W 07:18:19.766 NotebookApp] Session not found: session_id=u'e89223dd-d8e6-4104-b1ef-f161bc69a1b5'
[W 07:18:19.767 NotebookApp] 404 DELETE /api/sessions/e89223dd-d8e6-4104-b1ef-f161bc69a1b5 (10.66.192.88) 1.61ms referer=http://<host_name>:8888/notebooks/Untitled2.ipynb?kernel_name=ir
[I 07:18:20.131 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 5e7e650b-6fde-4b3f-ae03-8b8d67a0d4f5
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
[I 07:18:23.133 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
[I 07:18:26.137 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
[I 07:18:29.146 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
[W 07:18:31.002 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 5e7e650b-6fde-4b3f-ae03-8b8d67a0d4f5
[I 07:18:32.151 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5)
kernel 5e7e650b-6fde-4b3f-ae03-8b8d67a0d4f5 restarted
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/conda/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
```